# Pattern Atributte of a html5 form

Tags: regex, validation, pattern-matching, expression

I have this pattern expresion in my form: `(([Ee][xX][pP])|[Dd][Rr][aA])\d{0,5}/\d{2}`

and it works fine, but is there a better way to do the same?
I don't like to put twice every letter. I need a case-insensitive expresion that can match with eXp or Exp or exp.
Thanks =)

@davnull, i change the expresion, i thought that | was an or.

Comment: Why do you use `|` within a __character class__?

Comment: To clarify further, your regex would match `|||/42`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript, the i flag will match case-insensitively. This regex(I've maintained the same capturing groups in your original expression) should work -

```
((exp)|dra)\d{2,7}
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/zC7bF0)

EDIT -
HTML5 pattern attribute will always be case sensitive, since all the flags will be disabled. See [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute). So the only thing that you can do to shorten it would be the `\d{0,5}\d{2}` to `\d{2,7}`. So the resulting regex would be-

```
(([Ee][xX][pP])|[Dd][Rr][aA])\d{2,7}
```

Comment: hi! this doesn't match at pattern attr in html5 form.

Answer (score 0):

This is your pattern condensed to case insensitive.
What it matches, I don't know.

```
 #  (?i)((exp)|dra)\d{0,5}/\d{2}

 (?i)                  # Case insensitive
 (                     # (1 start)
      ( exp )               # (2)
   |  dra
 )                     # (1 end)
 \d{0,5} / \d{2}
```